# In flutter my build apk file is not working properly

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I have read all the available solutions on this topic none of them worked for me.I have deleted all build file using flutter clean and also uninstalled the app from the phone before every run
The apk file built using flutter run --release works fine.
The apk file built using flutter build apk doesn't working properly.
I don't know why it is happening?

My problem is similar to
[Android Studio generating old version APK](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59176581/13512631)

Comment: And also file size get increased in flutter build apk and I have also tried flutter build apk --release

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: I have added onboarding screen for new user + after login it should check whether the data is available in firebase or not. But in case of flutter build apk it is directly navigating to login screen.It is building the apk for older version code.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi But It is working fine when I build my apk using flutter run --release. I like to know why it is happening

Comment: You need to provide us the error message if you run "flutter build apk" in the project directory. Does "flutter doctor -v" print errors?

Comment: @Lukas There is no error message.After I install that apk it works like previous  version of that app

Comment: No @Lukas it is not showing any error

Comment: My problem is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/59176581/13512631 @ClaudioRedi

Comment: @SurajJha Please run the below commands in terminal, I think there might be issue of cache.

> flutter clean
> rm -rf pubspec.lock .packages .flutter-plugins
> flutter pub pub cache repair
> flutter packages get

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android Studio, I would recommend building the apk through the IDE.

On the top menu bar of Android Studio, select 'Build', 'Flutter', then 'Build APK'.

I haven't had any issues when building an app this way.

Comment: It's my first time I have experienced this.I have tried that too but it also doesn't worked

Comment: I have two laptop in both I'm facing same problem. Even my friend is facing the same problem

Comment: Try running flutter doctor in the command line to see if there is any issues with the framework or if there are any android licenses that haven't been accepted.

Comment: My problem is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/59176581/13512631

Answer (score 0):

*Do following:*

- flutter clean
- Check version number and name in the pubspec.yaml
- Open the Android part in Android Studio, try to build from there

Answer (score 0):

Do the following steps may be helpful for you

1. Open android studio do "Invalid Caches/Restart" from the menu bar
2. `flutter clean`  and try to make a build from android studio

Answer (score 0):

Although this method is a bit vague and old fashioned, but it still works.

**Step One:** Run your android device as a virtual emulator.

**Step Two:** Run main.dart in your android device. This will install the app in your device.

**Step Three:** Go to Play Store and install this app called APK Extractor.

**Step Four:** Extract your APK from the app.

The APKs created through this are smaller and more efficient as compared to the ones created using Android Studio and work pretty well.